# prestashop backup omitting cache folder?

Tags: backup, prestashop, lftp

im backing up my prestashop hosting with lftp (I havent got ssh/rsync access)

> lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow off; mirror --only-missing  --only-newer
>   public_html /var/www/example.com " -u p,w   ftp.example.com

can i omit all the cache folders from the backup?

Comment: Googling `lftp omit folder` seems to yield good results, are they not helpful?

Comment: yes - lftp will do it
 
Does it screw up anything by not backing up the cache directory  - either for when im trying new stuff on my non-production server or if disaster befalls and I need to restore everything .